# C# Discord.Net "Context"

Tags: c#, discord

I see everyone is using anything that is called "Context" and 90% define this with `Discord.Commands.SocketCommandContext`, now I want to create an bot which is able to read all users in a channel, without the use of commands, just when bot is connected it should bring an list with all users of the defined channel.

Everything I do doesn't works, it always just prints the name of the bot with the "#".

source part:

```
var guild = _client.GetGuild(1234);
        var channel = guild.GetChannel(1234);
        var users = guild.Users;
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            foreach (IGuildUser guser in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(guser);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for a Text Channel

```
var guild = this.client.GetGuild(123);
            var channel = guild.GetTextChannel(123);
            foreach (var user in channel.Users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user);
            }
```

This is for a Voice Channel

```
var guild = this.client.GetGuild(123);
            var channel = guild.GetChannel(123);
            foreach (var user in channel.Users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user);
            }
```

This is for a Guild

```
var guild = this.client.GetGuild(123);
            foreach (var user in guild.Users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user);
            }
```